# Installation Error for python-crfsuite on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation, python-crfsuite

I want to install crfsuite for python3 using

```
pip3 install python-crfsuite
```

but it throws an error.

```
Building wheel for python-crfsuite (setup.py) ... error

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
'"'"'/private/var/folders/v7/q8v7r4xs6bzc7fpl1xlb3zgh0000gn/T/pip-
install-jcwoi004/python-crfsuite/setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders
/v7/q8v7r4xs6bzc7fpl1xlb3zgh0000gn/T/pip-install-jcwoi004/python-
crfsuite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 
'"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders
/v7/q8v7r4xs6bzc7fpl1xlb3zgh0000gn/T/pip-wheel-evw_5zco --python-
tag cp37

       cwd: /private/var/folders/v7/q8v7r4xs6bzc7fpl1xlb3zgh0000gn
/T/pip-install-jcwoi004/python-crfsuite/

  Complete output (25 lines):

  running bdist_wheel

  running build

  running build_py

  creating build

  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7

  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pycrfsuite

  copying pycrfsuite/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-
x86_64-3.7/pycrfsuite

  copying pycrfsuite/_dumpparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-
x86_64-3.7/pycrfsuite

  copying pycrfsuite/_logparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-
x86_64-3.7/pycrfsuite

  running build_ext

  building 'pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite' extension

  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7

  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pycrfsuite

  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite

  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite/lib

  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite/lib/crf


     creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite
/lib/crf/src

  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite/swig

  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite/lib/cqdb

  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite/lib/cqdb/src

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/liblbfgs

  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/liblbfgs/lib

 gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-
common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g 
-Icrfsuite/include/ -Icrfsuite/lib/cqdb/include -Iliblbfgs/include 
-Ipycrfsuite -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
/3.7/include/python3.7m -c pycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.cpp -o 
build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.o -std=c99

  error: invalid argument '-std=c99' not allowed with 'C++/ObjC++'

  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------

  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-crfsuite

  Running setup.py clean for python-crfsuite

Failed to build python-crfsuite

Installing collected packages: python-crfsuite

  Running setup.py install for python-crfsuite ... error

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
'"'"'/private/var/folders/v7/q8v7r4xs6bzc7fpl1xlb3zgh0000gn/T/pip-
install-jcwoi004/python-crfsuite/setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders
/v7/q8v7r4xs6bzc7fpl1xlb3zgh0000gn/T/pip-install-jcwoi004/python-
crfsuite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 
'"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders
/v7/q8v7r4xs6bzc7fpl1xlb3zgh0000gn/T/pip-record-xhn2aymp/install-
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile

         cwd: /private/var/folders
/v7/q8v7r4xs6bzc7fpl1xlb3zgh0000gn/T/pip-install-jcwoi004/python-
crfsuite/

    Complete output (25 lines):

    running install

    running build

    running build_py

    creating build

    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7

    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pycrfsuite

    copying pycrfsuite/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-
x86_64-3.7/pycrfsuite

    copying pycrfsuite/_dumpparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-
x86_64-3.7/pycrfsuite

    copying pycrfsuite/_logparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-
x86_64-3.7/pycrfsuite

    running build_ext

    building 'pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite' extension

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pycrfsuite

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite/lib

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite/lib/crf

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite/lib/crf/src

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite/swig

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite/lib/cqdb

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/crfsuite
/lib/cqdb/src

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/liblbfgs

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/liblbfgs/lib

    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-
common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g 
-Icrfsuite/include/ -Icrfsuite/lib/cqdb/include -Iliblbfgs/include 
-Ipycrfsuite -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
/3.7/include/python3.7m -c pycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.cpp -o 
build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.o -std=c99

    error: invalid argument '-std=c99' not allowed with 
'C++/ObjC++'

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks
/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, 
setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders
/v7/q8v7r4xs6bzc7fpl1xlb3zgh0000gn/T/pip-install-jcwoi004/python-
crfsuite/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders
/v7/q8v7r4xs6bzc7fpl1xlb3zgh0000gn/T/pip-install-jcwoi004/python-
crfsuite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 
'"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders
/v7/q8v7r4xs6bzc7fpl1xlb3zgh0000gn/T/pip-record-xhn2aymp/install-
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the 
logs for full command output.
```

I haven't seen anyone else with the same problem, perhaps it's something obvious that I just can't see. I'm also new to MacOS and this didn't happen to me on Windows.
the pip version is 19.2.3 .
If somebody could please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues about this problem on the github repo, but are mostly closed with a reference to just use `conda install`, which is not really applicable in this case. [One of them](https://github.com/scrapinghub/python-crfsuite/issues/69) is mentioned in a [pull request](https://github.com/scrapinghub/python-crfsuite/pull/105) removing the flag causing the problem, so you might try installing from source, using the version from the pedning pull request like so:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/kvinwang/python-crfsuite.git@fix69
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I saw this post, but as you said, this was conda-specific and i do not have conda. I was looking for a way to work around installing conda.
As for your solution to use 

    pip install -e git+https://github.com/kvinwang/python-crfsuite/tree/fix69

I get this:

    ERROR: Could not detect requirement name for 'git+https://github.com/kvinwang    /python-crfsuite/tree/fix69', please specify one with #egg=your_package_name

Comment: @Bochjamin sorry, didn't get the syntax right for the `pip` call, fixed and tested now